# Forgot Password for firebase

Tags: firebase, forgot-password

I have developed a messenger application using firebase and I am trying to include forgot password but the below code is not working.Do I need to add any extra functionality for this code. I did not get the email nor did I get any log from firebase("password reset email sent"or"error encountered"). Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

```
 case R.id.forgot_pass_btn_forgotpass:
                   Log.e("","clickeddd");
                    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://boiling-torch-4946.firebaseio.com");
                    ref.resetPassword(forgotpassword, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            // password reset email sent
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                            // error encountered
                        }
                    });

            }
```

Comment: firebase automatically logs the output

Comment: I could not get back to this post previously. That is why I had posted it again. The logging is not my primary problem,I am not receiving forgot password in my mail? does anyone have a solution for that

Comment: The best solution would be to log some output and see what error is being produced. There are a large number of moving parts in delivering an email and it will be important to start by finding the point of failure.

Answer (score -1):

See this question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260541/7187895, here on Stack Overflow, on How To reset Firebase password.