# Forgot password in Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I believe there is a way for changing your password in Firebase but is there a way where the user forgets the password and can be assigned a new one or re-authenticated using email or SMS OTP.  I checked out on the net but couldn't seem to find one.

If there is a way how can it be implemented,  what all function calls need to be made. Could you direct me with an example.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to send a password reset email. See [this example from the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail("user@example.com")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: is this will also prevents user from enter the same password and is there any way to prevent the prevention?

Comment: There are no configuration options for the built-in email+password authentication provider. If you need that, you can consider creating your own provider.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, can this be done in app only? Means I want the new password to be set from my phone only..

Comment: What if Registered with mobile number?

Answer (score 12):

Reset Android FireBase Password

Java File

```
    public class ResetPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail;

    private Button btnReset, btnBack;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Enter your registered email id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)

                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lbl_forgot_password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password_msg"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/btn_reset_password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_back"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

This link to the docs should help you out:

[**DOCUMENTATION**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Firebase.html#changePassword-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.firebase.client.Firebase.ResultHandler-)

In short, Firebase has a method to use called changePassword, follow the link to find out how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Copied and pasted of [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users?hl=pt-br):

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String emailAddress = "user@example.com";

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try this method

```
private void resetpasswoord() {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String emailaddress = resest_email.getText().toString();
    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailaddress)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Your Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if Unity try this than

```
    string emailaddress = resest_email.text;
    FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SendPasswordResetEmailAsync(emailaddress).ContinueWith((task =>
    {

        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Email sent.");

        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Firebase.FirebaseException e =
           task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;

            GetErrorMessage((AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
            return;
        }

    }));

}
  void GetErrorMessage(AuthError errorcode)
{
    string msg = "";
    msg = errorcode.ToString();

    print(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simple method to send the reset password link on user email address with progress dialog (sometime firebase took time to complete *reset password* request because of slow internet connection on client side, so *progress dialog* will be helpful)

```
public void resetUserPassword(String email){
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ForgotPasswordActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("verifying..");
        progressDialog.show();

        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reset password instructions has sent to your email",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Email don't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If **Kotlin** is your language of choice you can use this:

```
val fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener({ listener ->
        if (listener.isSuccessful) {
            // Do something when successful
        } else {
            // Do something when not successful
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in Flutter, use this:

```
 @override
Future<void> resetPassword(String email) async {
    await _firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
}
```